# In Rails, why do I get a "can't write unknown attribute" when I try and save my model with non-nil state and country member fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, save, belongs-to, has-one

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have the following model …

```
class MyObjectTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_object
  has_one :state
  has_one :country
```

I’m having an issue when I try and save my entity with non-empty state and country objects.  I have

```
   state = State.find_by_iso_and_country_id(hometown_parts[1].strip!, us_country.id)
    country = state.country
    my_object_time = MyObjectTime.new(:name => my_object_time[2],
                             :age => my_object_time[7],
                             :time_in_ms => time_in_ms,
                             :overall_rank => my_object_time[1],
                             :city => city,
                             :state => state,
                             :country => country,
                             :gender_rank => my_object_time[7],
                             :my_object_id => my_object_id)
```

but unless both “state” and “country” are nil, I get the error

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError

can't write unknown attribute `my_object_time_id`
```

Everything will save fine if both these fields are nil.  What’s going on and how can I fix it?

**Edit:** Here is the PostGres description of the table in question

```
davedb=> \d my_object_times;
                                       Table "public.my_object_times"
     Column     |            Type             |                        Modifiers                        
----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                     | not null default nextval('my_object_times_id_seq'::regclass)
 my_object_id   | integer                     | not null
 first_name     | character varying           | 
 last_name      | character varying           | 
 time_in_ms     | bigint                      | 
 created_at     | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at     | timestamp without time zone | not null
 name           | character varying           | 
 age            | integer                     | 
 city           | character varying           | 
 state_id       | integer                     | 
 country_id     | integer                     | 
 overall_rank   | integer                     | 
 age_group_rank | integer                     | 
 gender_rank    | integer                     | 
Indexes:
    "my_object_times_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_my_object_times_on_country_id" btree (country_id)
    "index_my_object_times_on_my_object_id" btree (my_object_id)
    "index_my_object_times_on_state_id" btree (state_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_0fe1d25967" FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries(id)
    "fk_rails_a8771b3575" FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES states(id)
    "fk_rails_ba656ceafa" FOREIGN KEY (my_object_id) REFERENCES my_bojects(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "user_my_object_time_matches" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_2e7860946c" FOREIGN KEY (my_object_time_id) REFERENCES my_object_times(id)
```

Comment: your model MyObjectTime has country_id and state_id attributes?

Comment: The database table has those columns yes.  The model has "has_one :state" and "has_one :country", as I included at the top of my question.

Comment: your model state and country have my_object_time_id attribute? you are using has_one relationship. it say that foreing_key is in the state and country model. I think that the state_id and country_id foreing_keys are in the my_object_times table.. that is right? if it yes.. you must change has_one to belongs_to

Comment: No, state and country do not refernce the table.  I included the PostGres description of the table in my question if it is useful.  The foreign keys are listed in there.

Comment: so the anwser is Yes!! you need change has_one to belongs_to.

Comment: Awesome.  that worked.  thx for clarifying

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that if your table `my_object_times` has a `country_id` then it `belongs_to :country`. On the other side of the relationship, `country` `has_many :my_project_times`.